# Splinter - Element is not clickable because another element <p> obscures it

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am trying to get some thumbnail pictures from a website, from `src`, as well as click on a link, so I can later get the big picture.

For that I'm using `Splinter` with `BeautifulSoup`.

This is the `html`for the first element I need to get:

[image]

In order to do that I have the following code:

```
executable_path = {"executable_path": "/path/to/geckodriver"}
browser = Browser("firefox", **executable_path, headless=False

def get_player_images():

    url = f'https://www.premierleague.com/players'

    # Initiate a splinter instance of the URL
    browser.visit(url)

    browser.find_by_tag('div[class="table playerIndex"]')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.html, 'html.parser')
    for el in soup:
        td =  el.findAll('td')
        for each_td in td:
            link = each_td.find('a', href=True)
            if link:
                print (link['href'])
            image = each_td.find('img')
            if image:
                print(image['src'])
# run
get_player_images()
```

---

But I'm running into 2 issues, after browser opens:

I'm accessing only first two actual `src` for players. After that, photos are missing, which I don't get why.

```
/players/19970/Max-Aarons/overview
https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/p232980.png
/players/13279/Abdul-Rahman-Baba/overview
https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/p118335.png
/players/13286/Tammy-Abraham/overview
//platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/Photo-Missing.png
/players/3512/Adam-Smith/overview
//platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/Photo-Missing.png
/players/10905/Che-Adams/overview
....
```

Also, if I try to click on `href` link, with:

```
if link:
   browser.click_link_by_partial_href(link['href'])
```

I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a class="playerName" href="/players/19970/Max-Aarons/overview"> is not clickable at point (244,600) because another element <p> obscures it
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I'm running into a lot of troubles with selenium.

Comment: Do the photos of the player are loaded dynamically as you scroll the page?
Does the page has any cookie bar or anything else at the bottom of the page, that would block you from clicking?

Comment: @Jonah yes they are loaded dynamically. maybe I should do: `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(10000, document.body.scrollHeight);")` to make the page keep scrolling down, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player data is loaded dynamically via Javascript. You can use `requests` module to obtain the info.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=274&altIds=true&page={page}&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=274'
img_url = 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/{player_id}.png'
headers = {'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com'}

for page in range(1, 10):       # <--- increase this to desired number of pages
    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).json()

    # uncoment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for player in data['content']:
        print('{:<50} {}'.format(player['name']['display'], img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta'])))
```

Prints:

```
Ethan Ampadu                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p199598.png
Joseph Anang                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p447879.png
Florin Andone                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p93284.png
André Gomes                                        https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p120250.png
Andreas Pereira                                    https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p156689.png
Angeliño                                           https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p145235.png
Faustino Anjorin                                   https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p223332.png
Michail Antonio                                    https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p57531.png
Cameron Archer                                     https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p433979.png
Archie Davies                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p215061.png
Stuart Armstrong                                   https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p91047.png
Marko Arnautovic                                   https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p41464.png
Kepa Arrizabalaga                                  https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p109745.png
Harry Arter                                        https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p48615.png
Daniel Arzani                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p200797.png

... and so on.
```

Note: to get smaller thumbnails, change `250x250` in the image URLs to `40x40`